# Android Tablet paper.js on zoomed canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, paperjs

I got problem on Android Tablet (Galaxy Tab 2). When having a big image, and using paper.js to draw paths on it, everything is fine, but when I zoom the image (only if it is big enough), paper.js stops drawing paths on a certain width and height... the image on canvas is still being displayed (background-image with width and height set to 100%), but it seems that paper.js is unable to draw farther than some width and height. Any idea what is going on or how to fix it?

If something isn't well explained, please give me feedback. I really need to get it working. Today.

Comment: The problem is that it works fine on any other machine. Even on some tablets. On PC, everything is perfectly fine. I can give a link to preview site, but if you don't have that tablet, it may be impossible to replicate that problem.

Comment: You should post your code that draws the paths or make a fiddle/ plunkr to illustrate what you are doing.

Comment: Will do, gimme 30 minutes.